# Publish/Subscribe not working on Meteorjs mobile app

Tags: cordova, mobile, meteor

I have made a Cordova app with Meteorjs. Everything works great on web-browser, even on the simulators. But when I deploy it in on the device (meteor run android-device ) , the Publish/Subscribe does not work. The app stays in the loading-template (I use the iron-router). 
This is my publication :

```
Meteor.publish('days', function() {
    console.log("Publishing the DAYS :"+this.userId);
    return Days.find({userId:this.userId });
});
```

That log-message is never reached when the app runs on mobile. (But it does if I start the app from the browser)

And here is my subscribe :

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
    waitOn: function() {
        console.log("Waiton has run");

        return  [Meteor.subscribe('activities'),Meteor.subscribe('days')];
    }
});
```

The console displays the message "Waiton has run", but nothing more happens. 
I do not get ANY Error messages.

I have tried running "meteor run android-device --verbose", but the log seems good to me.

Right now I have gone out of ideas where to look, so any help or idea is welcome.

UPDATE : I just put my project on Github in case anyone wants to take a closer look. https://github.com/armaz/unitimelister

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are the files located that define the routes and the publication? Also you seem to assume the user is already logged in for the publication.

Comment: The file, router.js is in the lib-folder. Yes, I do assume that the user is already logged in because I have defined an "Router.onBeforeAction(function(pause) {.." where I send the not-logged users to another Page. But I see your point. That´s why I put the logging there to see what user-id is passed in. However it doesn´t even get there.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, "Router.onBeforeAction(function(pause) {.." is an old IronRouter pattern.

Comment: In your question you've said the "Waiton has run" is executed and displayed. Can you `console.log(Meteor.userId);`? Also to limit the probable causes does anything change if you remove the condition from the publication? Oh and try using the `Meteor.userId` (instead of `this.userId`).

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies all of you. I have now removed userId stuff completely from my publications, but still not working. I have removed any suspicious part from my code, like the Router.onBeforeAction(function(pause), but no result :( I will now start another project and move over to it to see when (or if) it will stop working then.